# Using BeautifulSoup to read articles from websites not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Apologies if this isn't a suitable question but I need some help. I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to read articles from websites. I have tried it on the BBC News website and it works okay. However when I use this website: http://dncapital.com/dn-capital-raises-new-e200m-fund/ it does not print the correct thing. What can I do? I have tried looking for other ways but it doesn't seem to work or it costs money. Here is my code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request


sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://dncapital.com/dn-capital-raises-new-e200m-fund/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')
source_stopwords=""
for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
    source_stopwords=source_stopwords+paragraph.text

print(source_stopwords)
```

but it doesn't print out the right thing. This is what it prints out.

```
Call us :   London: +44 (0)20 7340 1600 ⎪  Menlo Park: +1 (0)650 561 9300           Please click on the button below to submit your press enquiry. 

                                            Please fill in this form to subscribe to our mailing list.

                                        DN Capital (US) Inc.
2882 Sand Hill Road, Suite 210
Menlo Park
CA 94025
 +1 650 561 9300DN Capital (UK) LLP
2 Queen Anne's Gate Buildings
Dartmouth Street
London SW1H 9BP  +44 (0)20 7340 1600
 +44 (0)20 7340 1601
```

Comment: I'm not in a position to test right now but it looks to me like BBC puts paragraph text in the [p] html tag and dncapital uses the [h2] tag so maybe just try `for paragraph in soup.find_all('h2'):`

Comment: Looks like the right thing to me.

Comment: One solution for any specific site will not work for another unless they are identically structured. What is it you are trying to collect from that page?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have found for the BBC website will only work for other sites which have an identical structure. This is quite unlikely. That site would need to use the same CMS and the same page template (design).

> I have tried it on the BBC News website and it works okay.

The solution you found for the BBC website will even not work forever. BBC may change their website structure at any time in the future, thus breaking your implementation.

> What can I do?

You can change the code. If you don't want to change the code for each and every website, you need some clever way how your code figures out himself the way the website is structured. This could potentially involve statistics (e.g. headlines should be more seldom than text) or machine learning (e.g. you classify say 400 websites about their tags and after that the PC can do it for you).

> I have tried looking for other ways but it doesn't seem to work or it costs money.

Changing the code will result in hourly effort, thus cost. Change code, write a bill, get money. That's how software developers earn money, isn't it?